# I need to add a custom tabbar controller in appdelegate swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

tabBarItem1.title = @"Home";
tabBarItem2.title = @"Maps";
tabBarItem3.title = @"My Plan";
tabBarItem4.title = @"Settings";

[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps.png"]];
[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myplan_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myplan.png"]];
[tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"]];


// Change the tab bar background
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];

// Change the title color of tab bar items
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.0 green:192/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   titleHighlightedColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


return YES;
```

I have found this code in objective C. I need the same thing in swift. How can I get this. Please help as I am new to iOS.

I am trying to create a custom tabbar using swift.The above code is objective c code written in appdelegate.

Comment: [Objectivec2Swift](https://objectivec2swift.com/)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: No. The tab bar is not appearing. I am not able to navigate from my page to next page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var tabBarController = (self.window!.rootViewController! as! UITabBarController)
var tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar
var tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items()[0]
var tabBarItem2 = tabBar.items()[1]
var tabBarItem3 = tabBar.items()[2]
var tabBarItem4 = tabBar.items()[3]
tabBarItem1.title = "Home"
tabBarItem2.title = "Maps"
tabBarItem3.title = "My Plan"
tabBarItem4.title = "Settings"

tabBarItem1?.image = UIImage(named: "home.png")!
tabBarItem1?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")!
tabBarItem2?.image = UIImage(named: "maps.png")!
tabBarItem2?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "maps_selected.png")!
// same for tabBarItem3,tabBarItem4 so on ....

// Change the tab bar background
var tabBarBackground = UIImage(named: "tabbar.png")!
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = tabBarBackground
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "tabbar_selected.png")!
// Change the title color of tab bar items
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
var titleHighlightedColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(153 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(192 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(48 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : titleHighlightedColor], for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: For this code tabBarItem1?.setFinishedSelectedImage(UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")!, withFinishedUnselectedImage: UIImage(named: "home.png")!)
        tabBarItem2?.

Comment: It shows 'setFinishedSelectedImage(_:withFinishedUnselectedImage:)' is unavailable: Use initWithTitle:image:selectedImage: or the image and selectedImage properties along with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal

Comment: you can directly give the title ,image and selected image from storyboard

Comment: Use this
tabBarItem1?.image = UIImage(named: "home.png")!
tabBarItem1?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")!

Comment: Done. Thank you. Need one more help .I need to set my rootviewcontroller to "MyViewController" class. How can I achieve this in above code? Please help

Comment: this is different question but you can do directly from storyboard.
There is "Is innitial ViewController " check box just click it.  it become your first view controller load when your application is launch.

Comment: I am using xib here. How can I achieve this programatically?

Comment: get the viewcontroller from XIB then set 
self.window.rootViewController = YourViewController

Comment: And one more thing if my answer is helpful to you then Accept & upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Converted to Swift 3:

```
let tabBarController = (self.window!.rootViewController! as! UITabBarController)
let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar
let tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items?[0]
let tabBarItem2 = tabBar.items?[1]
let tabBarItem3 = tabBar.items?[2]
let tabBarItem4 = tabBar.items?[3]
tabBarItem1?.title = "Home"
tabBarItem2?.title = "Maps"
tabBarItem3?.title = "My Plan"
tabBarItem4?.title = "Settings"

tabBarItem1?.image = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")
tabBarItem2?.image = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")
tabBarItem3?.image = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")
tabBarItem4?.image = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")

tabBarItem1?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
tabBarItem2?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "maps_selected.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
tabBarItem3?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "myplan_selected.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
tabBarItem3?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "settings_selected.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

// Change the tab bar background
let tabBarBackground = UIImage(named: "tabbar.png")!
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = tabBarBackground
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "tabbar_selected.png")!

// Change the title color of tab bar items
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .normal)

let titleHighlightedColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(153 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(192 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(48 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: titleHighlightedColor], for: .highlighted)
```

**EDIT:**

Set rootViewController:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = MyVIewCOntroller()
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: @Rakesh Are you not using storyboard?

Comment: I am using xib.

Comment: Could you please show me how to set rootview controller in tabbarcontroller? I need to set rootview to my "MyVIewCOntroller" class.

Comment: @Rakesh Do you want to show `MyVIewCOntroller` before TabBarController?

Comment: Yes. exactly. I need that. But we can hide the tab bar manually from the viewcontroller in which I don't need the tabbar functionality right?

Comment: Ok. Now here in my "MyViewController" class I have a button which navigates to next class. But it;s not moving to the next page.

Comment: @Rakesh *I have a button which navigates to next class. But it;s not moving to the next page.* Now, This is separate question put your new question link here and I will take a look. If my answer helps then you can upvote and accept it.